# Sum over VLookup in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two sheets in a Microsoft Excel workbook:

```
| ID  | Name  | Total Sales |
-----------------------------
| ID1 | Name1 | ???1        |
| ID2 | Name2 | ???2        |
| ID3 | Name3 | ???3        |

| ID  | Value  |
----------------
| ID1 | 100,00 |
| ID2 |  50,00 |
| ID2 |  25,00 |
| ID1 |  15,00 |
```

I cannot find a formula for the `Total Sales` column which would produce 115 for ID1, 75 for ID2 and 0 for ID3.

I tried the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(OVERVIEW!A1;SALES!A:B;2;FALSE)
```

But of course, this only returns the very first sale and no total. How to extend the formula to lookup all matching values and sum them together?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found an answer myself:

```
=SUMIF(SALES!A:A; OVERVIEW!A1; SALES!B:B)
```